# Injecting service into Grails Atmosphere Handler class

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I have an NotificationsAtmosphereHandler as an Atmosphere framework handler class in my Grails application. I would like to use springSecurityService service inside of it. How I can inject service object into my handler class?

```
def springSecurityService
```

The usual service injection does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resources.xml:

```
 <bean id="notificationsAtmosphereHandler" class="your.package.NotificationsAtmosphereHandler"/>
```

in class:

```
class NotificationsAtmosphereHandler {
  .....
  @Autowired
  SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
  .....
}
```

Comment: the underlying reason why it didn't work is that your NotificationsAtmosphereHandler was not recognized by Grails as a bean that it should manage and instantiate. (It was not a service or a controller). Therefore you needed to configure its instantiation like in this answer

Comment: can you explain how to do this in grails 2.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

or rather do it the Groovy way in your resources.groovy:

```
import package.NotificationsAtmosphereHandler

//...

notificationsAtmosphereHandler(NotificationsAtmosphereHandler) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

this way, you don't need the @Autowired notation also.