# Not being able to inject services into AtmosphereHandler

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I am running Grails 2.2.1.
I have a Grails service, which acts as an atmosphere handler..
Refer this link: https://bitbucket.org/bgoetzmann/grails-atmosphere-plugin/wiki/Home

I am trying to use spring security service inside this, in your simple way, ie, by injecting it via `def springSecurityService`.
But when a service hits the handler, 
`springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()` returns null. 
User is logged in, I am able to get him in my controllers. I think the service is not injecting somehow.
After some research I came across this question 
[Injecting service into Grails Atmosphere Handler class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196928/injecting-service-into-grails-atmosphere-handler-class)

 but both answers are outdated...
Please help!

EDIT: my service goes like:

```
AtmosphereRequest req = r.getRequest();
 if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
     log.info "got get, and suspending."
     r.suspend();
     } else if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
         def data = req.getReader().readLine().trim()
         log.info "got some data:\n $data"
         if (data == "GET_NEARBY"){
             log.info "finding nearby..."
             def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
             log.info "user is $user" //USER IS NULL HERE

              //...some logic
         }
     }
```

Comment: Can you post the portion of the service class (atmosphere handler)? "But when a service hits the handler" - is bit confusing.

Comment: i've edited it.. this is within my `onRequest()` method

Comment: When you say you have Grails service, you meant you have a service class like `AtmosphereHandlerService` or `XyzService` created by the command `grails create-service`? Is that right?

Comment: yes, i've created a service with `grails create-service`

Comment: Do a grails clean and restart again, see if that helps.

Comment: dude i've done that like a million times... it's something more complex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def ctx = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
def springSecurityService = ctx. springSecurityService

    def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

now you should be able to use springSecurityService

Comment: i added: 
def ctx = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
 def springSecurityService = ctx.springSecurityService
 and it says  class [com.core.TripDiscovererService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'springSecurityService' on null object

Comment: ok i got `springSecurityService` now, but: `springSecurityService .getCurrentUser()` is null!

Comment: @AtharvaJohri def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser try this.